# Excel Import Data from SQL- Date comes in as text value

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ms-access, toad

I'm importing data from oracle toad database into an Excel sheet using data connection. The table includes a Date column, but this column comes to Excel as text rather than the date.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

```
Sub Show_data()


    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim iCols As Integer


    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset

'Check for the connectivity or connected to the xx network
    On Error GoTo errHandler


    ConnectionString = "Provider=xx;User ID=yy;password= appsro;Data Source=zz"

    con.Open ConnectionString

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'

        strSQL = "SELECT B.USER_NAME AS CREATED_BY, A.CREATION_DATE, C.USER_NAME, A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, A.PFIZER_ITEMCODE, A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE AS ORACLE_ITEM_CODE, " & _
        "A.ITEM_DESCRIPTION, A.BATCH_NUMBER, A.MFR_CODE, A.MFR_DESC AS MFR_DESCRIPTION, TO_CHAR(A.MFR_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')As MFR_DATE, TO_CHAR(A.EXPIRY_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')As EXPIRY_DATE, " & _
        "TO_CHAR(A.EFFECTIVE_FROM,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_FROM, " & _
        "A.EFFECTIVE_TO, A.EXCISE AS EXCISE_AMOUNT, A.EXCISE_RATE, A.P2S, A.P2R, A.MRP, A.STATE_CODE, A.STATE, " & _
        "(CASE SUBSTR(A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE,6,2) WHEN ('PI') THEN 'OIP' WHEN ('PF') THEN 'OPF' ELSE 'OWL' END )AS LEGAL_ENTITY " & _
        "FROM xxdhl_pf_batch_pricing A JOIN fnd_user B ON A.CREATED_BY = B.USER_ID " & _
        "JOIN fnd_user C ON A.LAST_UPDATED_BY = C.USER_ID WHERE "


        If (ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text) <> "" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " (CASE SUBSTR(A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE,6,2) WHEN ('PI') THEN 'OIP' WHEN ('PF') THEN 'OPF' ELSE 'OWL' END )='" & ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text & "'"
        End If

        If (ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text) <> "" Then
            If (ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text) <> "" Then
                strSQL = strSQL & " AND A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE='" & ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text & "'"
            Else
                strSQL = strSQL & " A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE='" & ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text & "'"
            End If
        End If

        If (ActiveSheet.txtBatch.Text) <> "" Then
            If (ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text) <> "" Or (ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text) <> "" Then
                strSQL = strSQL & " AND A.BATCH_NUMBER='" & ActiveSheet.txtBatch.Text & "'"
            Else
                strSQL = strSQL & " A.BATCH_NUMBER='" & ActiveSheet.txtBatch.Text & "'"
            End If
        End If

        If (ActiveSheet.txtfromdt.Text) <> "" Then
            If (ActiveSheet.txtfromdt.Text) <> "" And (ActiveSheet.txtTodt.Text) <> "" Then

            Else
                strSQL = strSQL & " AND TRUNC(A.EFFECTIVE_FROM) BETWEEN TO_DATE('" & ActiveSheet.txtfromdt.Text & "','DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE ,'DD-MON-YYYY') "
            End If
        End If

        If (ActiveSheet.txtfromdt.Text) <> "" And (ActiveSheet.txtTodt.Text) <> "" Then
            If (ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text) <> "" Or (ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text) <> "" Or (ActiveSheet.txtBatch.Text) <> "" Then
                strSQL = strSQL & " AND TRUNC(A.EFFECTIVE_FROM) BETWEEN TO_DATE('" & ActiveSheet.txtfromdt.Text & "','DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('" & ActiveSheet.txtTodt.Text & "','DD-MON-YYYY') "
            Else
                strSQL = strSQL & " TRUNC(A.EFFECTIVE_FROM) BETWEEN TO_DATE('" & ActiveSheet.txtfromdt.Text & "','DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('" & ActiveSheet.txtTodt.Text & "','DD-MON-YYYY') "
            End If
        End If



    'Open Recordset

    Set recset.ActiveConnection = con
    If recset.State = adStateOpen Then recset.Close
    recset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    recset.Open strSQL, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    For iCols = 0 To recset.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = recset.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    'Copy the data
    If recset.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset recset
    Else
    MsgBox "No Data Available", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, ""
    Exit Sub
    End If




recset.Close
con.Close


errHandler:
    If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
        MsgBox "Please check for the xx connectivity ", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

> Actual result - 6/5/2015 4:12:47 PM but In Excel - 42160.67554

Please help :(

Comment: it is correct- your Excel value is correct date without formatting. You need to apply required date format in either your SQL code or VBA code or manually in Excel.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor....hi pls give any e.g. to do through code

Comment: check `Format functions` in both SQL and VBA. I can't see in which way you use VBA in your solution. Show your VBA code in question for further support.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor..hi i have edited my code...please check if you can find out anything.

Comment: In my opinion all what you need is @joehanna answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which columns are you referring to as you have a mixture of logic when it comes to dates in your SQL query.

`CREATION_DATE` and `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` should work fine and simply need formatting like @KazimierzJawor said. Something like:-

```
  Range("B5:B10, D5:D10").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
```

If you are referring to `MFR_DATE`, `EXPIRY_DATE` and `EFFECTIVE_FROM` columns, then you should remove the `TO_CHAR` functions as this is forcing the data to be text.  Once you have removed the functions, you should be able to format those columns using the same technique as shown above.

Comment: @joe...above is the simple soution you given and thanks for that...but it will look bad coding in my VBA.
i have edited my full coding....please check and let me know if there is any other way...

Comment: @KalpeshKoli, what does it mean 'bad coding'? Joehanna answer is what you should try to apply.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor....hey sorry bad choice of words but i was thinking for different solution which will format the data of recordset. However i will have this soution only and meanwhile check for another solution if any..